# Function symbols in windows executeable

Tags: c++, visual-c++, name-mangling

I want to get a list of with the mangled names of all functions of an executeable for some external analysis.

On Linux this a an easy task. I just need to compile as usual and run `nm` to get a list with the mangled names.

```
$ nm test    
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U printf
                 U __stack_chk_fail
0000000000000012 T _Z3fooi
0000000000000000 T _Z3foov
0000000000000007 T _Z4footv
0000000000000000 W _ZN3BarC1Ev
0000000000000000 W _ZN3BarC2Ev
0000000000000000 n _ZN3BarC5Ev
```

On windows and microsoft's visual c++ (msvc?) I can't figure a way to get information in the same way.
I tried compiling my application with `cl /Od /DEBUG` and run `dumpbin /EXPORTS /HEADERS` but I don't get a list of the mangled function names of my application.

```
dumpbin /EXPORTS test.exe
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.00.24245.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Dump of file test.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

Summary

2000 .data
1000 .gfids
1000 .pdata
9000 .rdata
1000 .reloc
C000 .text
Type a message
```

Is `dumpbin` only working on shared libraries instead of executables?
Since I only need all mangled names (e.g. _Z3foov, _ZN3BarC1Ev) without changing my application code, is there a better solution to get this strings?
I'm usually developing c++ application on linux. Therefore I don't know much about windows specifics.

Comment: You should look at .pdb debug symbols. Also note that it is not an easy task (even on linux) if executable is build without debug symbols. Actually it is pretty much the opposite.

Comment: Where to find / how to access this .pdb debug symbols? I only get my exe and an .obj file running `cl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio, you're looking for the "MAP file". The linker option is `/MAP`, it's found under the "Debugging" properties in Visual Studio. This is generated as part of the build, not afterwards. The output is a simple text file similar to `nm` output.